# scroll not reaching end of page before loading more users

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading information as i scroll down on a page. But currently as i start scrolling more information is being downloaded to display. Is there a way to get the scroll to reach the end of the page shows a quick message for like 2 seconds "loading more images" and then shows the next batch.

```
 function updateStatus() {

// Load more users on Scroll
$('#main').scroll(function () {
    if ($('#main').scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $('#main').height()) {
        $('#status').text('Loading more items...');
        $('#users').append(Next());
    }
    setTimeout('updateStatus();', 1500);
});
}
```

**AFTER SUGGESTED ANSWERS UPDATE**

```
function updateStatus() {
        $('#users').append(Next());
    }

    // Load more users on Scroll
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#main').scroll(function () {
            if ($('#main').scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $('#main').height())) {
                $('#status').text('Loading more items...');
            }

        });
        setTimeout(updateStatus, 2500);
    });
```

With current edit when i scroll to the bottom of the page it loads the next 20 users but then reaching the end of the page again it doesn't load any more. But when i take the `setTimeout(updateStatus, 2500)` and place it within `$('#main').scroll...` when i scroll without a little reaching the bottom of the page data keeps loading and loading before reaching the end of the page.

---

```
Next = function () {
    var _page = $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage() + 1;
    $.views.Roster.GetPage("/api/Roster", 9, _page);
};

$.views.Roster.GetPage = function (url, id, pageNumber) {
        $.grain.Ajax.Get({
            Url: url,
            DataToSubmit: { pageNumber: pageNumber, id: id },
            DataType: "json",
            OnSuccess: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);
                $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage(pageNumber);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: check out [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: have you tried setTimeout function?

Comment: @guggly yes - i just updated my code and now i am not loading data at all which loaded before wrapping what i had in `updateStatus()` and setting `setTimeout()`

Comment: you have to move your event handler outside the function declaration. Right now, `updateStatus()` never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After massive research and helpful answer suggestions from users on this post this is what i came up and it finally worked as i wanted it:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main').scroll(function () {
        var div = $(this);
        if (div[0].scrollHeight - div.scrollTop() == div.height()) {
            Next();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this? (untested code)

```
function updateStatus() {
    $('#status').text('');
    $('#users').append(Next());
}

// Load more users on Scroll
$('#main').scroll(function () {
    if ($('#main').scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $('#main').height()) {
        $('#status').text('Loading more items...');
        setTimeout(updateStatus, 1500);
    }

});
```

Comment: getting closer - just tried this and on the first time it waits tell i am towards the bottom then it loads the next batch and then starts loading everything. So works for the first time but not after that

Comment: idk, really. Maybe put the scroll event handler on `$(window)` instead of `#('#main')`. Also, perhaps a couple `console.log()`'s to see what is actually being executed... can't really spare the time right now to debug for you.

Comment: thanks for your help i will go off what u just mentioned and test around and see what i get and hopefully it will something simple.

Answer (score 1):

**

> Updated program

**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( 
    function(){
    $(window).scroll(
    function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()== $(document).height()-$(window).height()) //End of Page
        {
            $("#status").html(function(n){// For Loading
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#wrapper").append(function(n){// Add the users here
                        $("#status").html("");

                            return "<p><br/><br/><br/>Added</p>";
                        });
                }, 2000);
                return "<p>Loading...</p>";
                });

        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">


<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><b

r/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/

><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
Hello

        <div id="wrapper"></div>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I will update my code and explain my current issue - hopefully its fix will be quick because this looks like i will have to change a lot.

Comment: Ok so i updated my code and what is happening with it - maybe you can help me out with it.

Comment: I explained it in the update above. Currently when i scroll to the bottom of the page it loads the next set of information and then stops when i scroll to the bottom of the page it doesn't load anymore. And when i place the setTimeout within the scroll function. I get data loaded as a scroll but not waiting till i reach the end of the page.

Comment: Either i am doing something wrong or the suggestion didn't make a difference.

Comment: OK. Don't you think that its better to show the new posts when the data is successfully received from the server side?

Comment: I just added a new code in my section. replace everything with that. add the necessary append codes. No need to change the id of the new divs

Comment: do i have to add this in my scroll `$.ajax({ url: "server.php?count=20",data:datas, success: function(data)` because i have my `Next()` gets the same thing.

Comment: Am using that for removing the status and adding the new divs. Actually these are triggered when ajax success is true. If your `Next()` doesn't have those, then add them in it.

Comment: Done!!! Just paste this whole code in a fresh html page so that you can see how its working. You can add `Next()` in the place provided. I hope this helps.

Comment: This looks very helpful thanks! Is this script supposed to be embedded in the html page? I have mine in a separate file

Comment: Just tried it and this is what it does: by default i get 20 items on page as i scroll and at the bottom of the page i get the remaining 370 items. I am supposed to get 20 at a time for every scroll to the bottom of page.

Comment: Actually i dont understand your 'Next()'. But this is what you should do in 'Next' - Keep a var count=20, then get only 20 users every time 'Next()' is called. this limit of 20 should be done in your server side code so that only 20 users are sent at a time.

Comment: From your 'Next()' function, I understand that you are getting data. But where are you limiting your data to return 20 users?

Comment: In my controller- i specify 20 items per page for a url and in my javascript i get more pages for the url and it will display batches of result in 20. Is there a way to hard code so that the scroll goes to the bottom?

Comment: Yes, everytime you get the 20 users in client side, you can call this 'window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);'